# Getting text from bootstrap alert

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, capybara

I am attempting to test my rails app's alert messages. I have the following code that is produced inside of Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<div class="alert fade in alert-success">
   <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
   Signed out successfully.
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is pull out just the "Signed out successfully."

At the moment I have:

```
def alert_text
   @page.find('div.alert').text
end
```

But that gives me "× Signed in successfully."

In my test I am doing:

```
assert_equal "Signed in successfully.", my_page.alert_text
```

If I change the assertion to include the `×`, I am getting a `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` error. Is there an easy way to pull out the text and ignore the button? I would wrap the text in a separate div, but it is generated in the gem so I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Since its hard to see what else is going on, I would add a custom element with `id="signedOut"` or something around the specific text, and access it by id. It won't mess with your boostrap styling.

Alternatively, try being more specific in the find. You may be using two classes that start with alert.

```
def alert_text
   @page.find('div.alert fade in alert-success').text
end
```

If you have two div's using this class, you can add on to the end of it or just go into the class definition in your bootstrap folder and add one more layer to it. (Bootstrap uses js and css just like the rest of us, although it helps get things off the ground pretty quickly).

Comment: I appreciate the thought but as I mentioned the div is generated in the gem so I cannot add a separate ID.